# slow disk I/O speed on NTFS partition

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, ntfs

My Laptops internal 640 GB HDD ,WD Scorpio blue(WD6400BPVT). It has 5 partitions.

- 120 GB NTFS partition, primary, sda1
- 250 GB NTFS, extended, sda5
- 20 GB / (root), sda6
- 4 GB /swap, sda7
- ~ 202 GB /home, sda8

Those two NTFS partitions due to previous windows installation, but read/write speed on NTFS partitions is only around 42 MB/s, while read/write speed on ext4 partitions are over 85 MB/s. I'm am geting such slow speed since installed Ubuntu 14.04 .

What is the Problem ?

**note**

- I had defragmented both NTFS partitions before Installing Ubuntu
- I also tried to defragment with this command, but no luck.

`fsck -t ntfs --kerneldefrag /dev/sda`

Comment: `fsck -t ntfs --kerneldefrag /dev/sda` does defrag on the whole disk where a valid NTFS structure doesn't even exist (well, you can't find the proper offsets for NTFS stuffs then), not on your partitition `/dev/sda<num>`. Also try raw reading speed testing like `dd if=/dev/sda<num> of=/dev/null bs=128M count=16` so you can confirm it's not a problem with the disk and there's really something to do with ntfs-3g. Many hard drives get slower as the physical location of the data on the disk gets to the inner tracks. Not-that-native filesystems are quite likely to be slow, so don't be surprised.

Comment: I did raw read speed test with `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null bs=128M count=16` , it is showing speed around 112 MB/s , surprising ! why ?

Comment: So NTFS is the one to blame now.

Comment: Is slow speed  normal for NTFS partitions on linux ? as written on the 1st answer by _petry_. Is there any workaround for this problem other than backup the data and format NTFS partitions to ext4 ? It will b great if you write your comment as an answer.

Comment: @MingyeWang no, the thing to blame is the FUSE ntfs-3g driver, which is obviously slow, being a userspace driver. The new NTFS kernel driver is very fast

Answer (score 5):

Found [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930429) on ubuntuforums where the OP found mounting their NTFS partition with the sync option in their fstab was causing the slowness. Sure enough, after removing `sync` from my NTFS partition entry in `/etc/fstab`, I observed a dramatic speedup on all file access.

Answer (score 2):

NTFS is a proprietary file system (MS). Everything `ntfs-3g` is able to do was achieved by reverse engineering. Considering the above, I would not expect a proprietary file system to be as fast as an open file system (under linux).

Now, if NTFS should be only 20% slower than ext4 (instead of 50%) in your case, i do not know, but i'm sure you can have a clean NTFS partition to do some tests (if you're not using swap frequently, you can format it as NTFS and do some testing).

Comment: @ petry , as you mentioned , soon I will do a test with cleanly formated NTFS partition, by formating the swap partition.